# Django rest framework: Social Auth + JWT: Which third party packages are preferred to achieve this

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am developing a mobile application for which Django rest framework provides the api.

I want a login system with username+password and google and facebook options

I have gone through the `https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/`

I mentions many third party packages in the end.

Can someone guide me, how to achieve my goal using which combination of third party packages.

I have used django-allauth previously but it has no rest support.

Answer (score 1):

`django-allauth` has support in DRF also but it is used in `django-rest-auth` (latest fork `dj-rest-auth`).

I think that should be what you want, `dj-rest-auth`. That has all the features, like register, login, logout, email verification, password reset, social authentication.

Comment: Please mark as accepted if this solved your problem

Comment: Instead of `dj-rest-auth` can i use `django-rest-knox` here

Comment: Django-rest-knox just provides a more secure token authentication and doesnot provide any other auth features. You need to use that with either the default auth system of django or any third party package.  That just provides token authentication

Comment: How to use django-know for social logins

Comment: So if i got you right, you want to use social login as well as token authentication. I tihnk they are different. Social logins will generate their own tokens for authentication and django-rest-auth is for generating token when someone logs in normally, like using username and password.

Comment: I never did social authentication via rest api. But I know Oauth givess access_token and refresh_token and we have to collect them at the redirect url on ones server.  I will check into this more. So you say `dj-rest-auth` also takes care of this